# How is this type of matrix called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

Let the matrix $M$ be defined as:
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}\right)$$

where $A = 0,B,C,D = 0$ are block matices and $B$ is a diagonal matrix and $C$ is a diagonal matrix.

Example:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 128 \\
256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 256 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it seems a balanced bipartite adjacency matrix

Comment: @Exodd: Thanks I will look this up.

Comment: @Exodd: I looked it up, but I am not sure if it is the same type of matrix.

Comment: Actually $M$ is called a block matrix (and not $A,B,C,D$, which are the blocks themselves).

Comment: Then it is (up to similarity with diagonal matrices) a circulant matrix

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Exodd: Thanks, I thought first about circulant matrices, but I can not see how they are up to similarity circulant matrices.

Comment: Maybe helpful: this is an example of a [generalized permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix)

Comment: @BenGrossman: That's it! Thanks.